# how to avoid creating Makefile for an subdir in QT pro file

Tags: qt, makefile, profile

Before compile my program ,I need to compile a 3rd party library,but it is not writen in QT ,it has a Makefile to build itself . so if I write a pro file like this:

TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += image myapp

(image directory is the 3rd party library)

then qmake,make
it always report "Cannot find file: image.pro"
if I write a pro file inside image, it will create a Makefile which will overwrite the original Makefile.

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try several things, depending on what you want:

1. Use `QMAKE_MAKEFILE` to rename the qmake-generated makefile so that is won't overwrite the other one.
2. do some fancy stuff to create something like a QMAKE_PRE_BUILD sort of thing (this variable does *not* exist in qmake):

   makefile.target      = Makefile
   makefile.depends    += prebuild
   prebuild.target      = prebuild
   prebuild.depends     = FORCE
   prebuild.commands    = @echo before build (to replace)
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += makefile
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += prebuild

Source: http://forum.qtfr.org/viewtopic.php?id=10686 (read post two and three (google translate) and keep in mind that "défaut" wich means defect gets translated as default :) )

These should be able to solve the problem you're having.